# Validation on relation between parameters, with hapijs/joi

Tags: javascript, node.js, hapi.js, joi

I am trying to validate optional parameters from a querystring that are depending on each other. In other words, when parameter A is added, parameter B is also needed. Both parameters are optional, so when neither of them are provided validation should also pass.

Should pass:

```
?a=1&b=2&c=0
?c=0
```

Should fail:

```
?a=1&c=0
?b=2&c=0
```

Can someone give me an example schema on how to solve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at [Joi.object().and()](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/v7.2.3/API.md#objectandpeers)

```
Joi.object().keys({
  a: Joi.number(),
  b: Joi.number(),
  c: Joi.number()
}).and('a', 'b');
```

Comment: Thanks, that does exactly what I want :-) I know set the whole query validation part as a Joi object and apply the 'and' rule.